# Django- Feeding **kwargs into .aggregate()

Tags: django, django-queryset

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
outputs = {"total_kgs": "kgs"}
Model.objects.all().aggregate(**outputs)
```

in place of:

```
Model.objects.all().aggregate(total_kgs="kgs")
```

Right now I am getting:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'

Here is what I am currently trying to do:

class InventoryManager(Manager):

```
def lookup(self, operators, fields, status, labels=None):
    outputs = {}

    if status == "unsold":
        operators.update({"status__lt": choices.SOLD})

    q = [Q(**operators)]

    for field in fields:
        label = labels.pop(0) if labels else "{}_total".format(field)
        outputs.update({label: field})

    return self.model.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, q)).aggregate(**outputs)

def total_kgs(self, status='unsold'):

    operators = {"supplier__market__weights": "KGS"}
    operators.update({'supplier__market__currency_code':"INR"})
    return self.lookup(operators, ["weight", "invoice_value"], status)
```

Relevant model data:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    invoice = models.CharField(max_length=24, unique=True)
    lbs = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=48, blank=True, null=True)
    kgs = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=48, blank=True, null=True)
    invoice_value = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=48, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=choices.STATUS_CHOICES, default=choices.PENDING)
```

Here is ultimately what I would like to do for each query:

```
self.model.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, q)).aggregate(total_weight=Coalesce(Sum("weight"), 0))
```

Comment: The problem is not the dict expansion, it's the expression itself. `aggregate` doesn't expect a string where you are passing `"kgs"`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm going to be aggregating a lot of different things at various times, so I thought I could build dictionaries to pass into a function that would unpack and run the query. I'll post some code.

Comment: You can certainly do that, but the arguments have to be the right ones. Your query wouldn't work even if you passed then explicitly.

Comment: You are right. I am forgetting the math >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So whaddya know. If you plug in the right expressions, it works just fine. Thanks again.

```
for field in fields:
    label = labels.pop(0) if labels else "{}_total".format(field)
    outputs.update({label: Coalesce(Sum(field), 0)})
```